# How to replace (copy paste) non alpha characters in the textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My requirement is like I need to replace non alpha characters in the text box i achieved it only if the user types in the text box, but if the user copy paste some values like this

> "asd5653tYgh45Ghgs34gthth65TGhd"

the values are not replaced as expected . Here **65** is not replaced, to replace it   I need to do keyup or keypress again, after that only the value is replaced. I've attached the jsfiddle link for your reference.

**Code:**

**Html:**

```
Name :<input type='text' id='txtName' />
```

**jQuery:**

```
$("#txtName").on('keyup keypress',function(){
    var pattern = /^[a-zA-Z]+$/;
    var txtval = $("#txtName").val();
    if(!pattern.test(txtval)){
       $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[^a-zA-Z]+/,''))
    }
});
```

**Link:**

[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9knXh/4/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

here is your solution: http://jsfiddle.net/9knXh/9/
the new pregmatch is `/[^a-zA-Z]+/g` the g at the end means do all except for only 1
so the new code:

```
$(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[^a-zA-Z]+/g,''))
```

EDIT: i also added change for the people who use the right mouse paste

Comment: I edited the code btw. becouse the chnage needs to be there for people who use right mouseclick paste

Answer (score 2):

use g at end to resolve your issue

http://jsfiddle.net/9knXh/7/

```
$("#txtName").on('keyup keypress',function(){
    var pattern = /^[a-zA-Z]+$/;
    var txtval = $("#txtName").val();
    if(!pattern.test(txtval)){
       $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[^a-zA-Z]+/g,''))
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
$("#txtName").on('keydown', (function() {
    var keyCode = (event.keyCode) ? event.keyCode : event.which;
    var isCtrl;
    isCtrl = event.ctrlKey
    if (isCtrl) {
        if ('v' == String.fromCharCode(keyCode).toLowerCase()) {
             `enter code here`
        }
    }
    return true;
});
```